# control of a Sonos speaker by a 3rd party application

Tags: sonos

I have looked at API provided by Sonos labs. This API is dedicated to music providers. 
Is there a public API to control volume of Sonos speakers ?

Comment: Hi Isabelle. This is a question that should be directed to Sonos' website. See here to understand what questions are appropriate and on-topic for StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the cloud based APIs enable control of both the group and individual players. Check out https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/group-volume/ and https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playervolume/ .